# How to stop variable symbols from being exported macOS

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, unix

So I've got my main program that uses `dlsym` to find the symbols of 2 functions and a variable from a dylib and I have a variable that I don't want exported.

My problem is that whether or not I use `extern "C"` for the variable `dlsym` will always find the variable Im not exporting, if I remove `extern "C"` from the functions they're not found by `dlsym` in the program but no matter what it'll always find the variables.

Code for the dylib :

```
export "C" char exported_var[2] = { 'a', '\0' };

extern "C" void dylib_quit()
{
    ...
}

extern "C" void dylib_main()
{
    ...
}

char hidden_var1[2] = { 'b', '\0' }; // dlsym will still find this
char hidden_var2[2] = { 'b', '\0' }; // dlsym will still find this
```

Code for the program :

```
// I want to find all these and I can
dylib_main_fn m_main_fn = (dylib_main_fn)dlsym(handle, "dylib_main");
dylib_quit_fn m_quit_fn = (dylib_quit_fn)dlsym(handle, "dylib_quit");
const char* exported_var = (const char*)dlsym(m_handle, "exported_var");

// And when I do this it will find the "hidden_var1" variable which I don't want happening
// same with "hidden_var2"
const char* hidden_var1 = (const char*)dlsym(m_handle, "hidden_var1");
```

So how am I able to hide the variable?
Im using Xcode 11.3.1 on MacOS 10.14.6.

Comment: `extern "C"` does not control whether functions and variables are exported or not. They are exported anyway. It just controls whether the symbol is given a C name or a C++ name. The latter one includes type information (aka as C++ name mangling).

Comment: Also see [Dynamic Library Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html), in particular the section *Symbol Exporting Strategies*. It's old documentation but likely still valid.

Comment: @Codo ah thank you, I'll give that a look, the thing I read gave the impression that `extern "C"` was used to export symbols

Comment: @Codo Ive hidden the symbols but now I can't make them visible using the visibility default attribute, any ideas why?

Comment: Fixed it, having to use `extern "C"` along with the visibility attribute

Comment: Please add an answer showing how you did it.

Comment: @Codo Added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding symbols using -fvisibility=hidden

Exporting

Code for the dylib :

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))

EXPORT char exported_var[2] = { 'a', '\0' };

EXPORT void dylib_quit()
{
    ...
}

EXPORT void dylib_main()
{
    ...
}

char hidden_var1[2] = { 'b', '\0' };
char hidden_var2[2] = { 'b', '\0' };
```

Comment: Where exactly do you specify `-fvisibility=hidden`? In one of the many Xcode settings?

Comment: @Codo Using XCode, Project target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Compiler Flags